# new File(uri.toString()) returns file not found

Tags: android, file, uri

I have a URI and I want to create a file from this URI:

```
fileUri = file:///mnt/sdcard/20120904_162830.png;

File fichero = new File(fileUri.toString();
```

This works fine but when I try to create use or `fichero.exist() = false`

How can I create a file from this `fileUri`?

Solution:

```
fichero = new File(fileUri.getPath());//for camera
                    if (!fichero.exists()) {
                        fichero = new File(getRealPathFromURI(fileUri));//for gallery
                    }


public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File fichero = new File(fileUri.getPath());
```

Comment: If i get the file from a gallery intent doesnt work, but i take a photo yes.

Comment: What happens when you do `android.util.Log.v("FILE", "-->["+fichero.getAbsolutePath()+"]");`? Does that print out the right path? Do you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` like @gtumca-MAC pointed out? And does the file actually exist?

Comment: Write_external_storage its in manifiest, the file exists because i select it from gallery android fichero.getabsolutepatch:  /external/images/media/68

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
File output = new File(dir,"20120904_162830.png");
```

add this permission to manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**EDIT :**

```
String filename= output.getAbsolutePath();
filename= str.subString(str.indexOf("/"),str.length());
```

Comment: Thats ok but how i cant get only the filename.fileextension

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
fileUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/20120904_162830.png";

URI fUri = new URI(fileUri);

File fichero = new File(fileUri.getPath());
```

This works only if you are not giving any web address in fileUri

Comment: If i get the file from a gallery intent doesnt work, but i take a photo yes